# Filtering a mongodb query using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to filter a mongoDB documents based on specific properties.
Here's what i'm trying to do.
lets say i have a user doc and within this User doc i have like 10 fields. out of these 10 fields i want to filter my query to get just about 4.

i tried something like this

```
UserDoc.find({}, email:1, dob:1, hasInsurance:1, isMarried:1)
```

This is assuming that i only want the query to return these specific fields. I saw this approach here on SO but doesn't seem to work. could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: your question is not clear, are you trying *these specific fields* **or** *filter a mongoDB documents based on specific properties.*, both are different things, the first parameter is for query and the second is for projection see more about [find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) function.

Comment: its more of the latter. i am trying to filter a mongoDB documents based on specific properties. thanks

Comment: `.find({ email: "", bob: "", hasInsurance: "", isMarried: "" })`, please see the attached link in first comment for find method, and this is a basic question you have to look at the documentation before asking question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the mongo shell try:

```
UserDoc.find({}, {email:1, dob:1, hasInsurance:1, isMarried:1})
```

and with mongoose in nodejs use:

```
UserDoc.find({}).select("email dob hasInsurance isMarried")
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. This is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

In nodejs you can use below syntax to get specific filed in output-

```
UserDoc.find({}).select("email").select("dob").select("hasInsurance").select("isMarried")
```

You can remove specify filed from output . It will only remove email filed from the output-

```
UserDoc.find({}).select("-email")
```